# Rotate from -9 to 9 degress automatically

Tags: javascript, image, css, rotation

I currently have this code

```
-webkit-transition: 0.9s;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-9deg);
-moz-transition: 0.9s;
-moz-transform: rotate(-9deg);
-o-transition: 0.9s;
-o-transform: rotate(-9deg);
-ms-transition: 0.9s;
-ms-transform: rotate(-9deg);
```

I would like it so that my image will rotate to -9 and then to 9 and then repeat itself over and over again. So that the whole time someone is on the site it will just rotate from -9 degress to 9 degress

Edit: I have been told that JavaScript is needed to do this, so I am now looking for some JavaScript to do this.

Thanks

Comment: javascript would help you

Comment: you'd need some js to toggle between -9 and +9. css by itself is not programmable to do this sort of thing, though animation capability of some sort is in the CSS3 specs.

Comment: Anyone got some javascript code that would do this?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Comment: I hope you have a really good reason to use this. Perpetually moving objects is generally considered bad web design because it's distracting. That's what we had with all the flash websites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations), depending on [how much compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) you need.

```
div {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.9s;
    -webkit-animation-name: ninetonine;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes ninetonine {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(9deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-9deg);
    }
}
```

[See a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/LBSHC/3/)

Comment: I like this one but it is buggy in Firefox, any fixes?

Comment: @iKeirNez: Here's an implementation that works nicely in FF≥16: http://jsbin.com/elelag/4/edit . For other browsers you need to add browser prefixes or a fallback to javascript.